# ActiveX doesn't appear on IE

Tags: activex

I have an ActiveX control in my project. It has been working properly for over a year. But the API, which I used when coding it, has changed. So I recoded the whole ActiveX control using the new API. I want the old ActiveX to continue working, so I changed the GUID and product code of activex which I recoded. It works fine on my developing computer. But when I install the control on another computer, it does not appear on IE.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least a dozen possible things that this could be; however, given the amount of information you have provided it is nearly impossible to do more than guess wildly.

Are you using a 32 bit control with a 64 bit browser on the "[other] computer"? Or vise versa?

How are you installing it? Are there any error messages? Yellow bars? Does it show up in the Manage Add-ons screen?

You might also consider using [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) instead of coding the ActiveX yourself; that way it'd work in other browsers as well and you don't have to muck with the ActiveX directly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thank you for your reply.

I am using a 32 bit control on a 32 bit computer.

I am installing it with the msi installer which is produced by my project. There are no error messages. But when I try to load it first, yellow bar appears and asks my permission. After I give the permission it does not appear at all. No error messages are shown. Neither this nor the old (and working)activex shows up in the Manage Add-ons screen.

I didn't know about FireBreath, but I don't think I will be allowed to use it. I am going to look at it though.